Fancyhdr automatic header height
I am trying to write a simple document with a header and a footer on each page. I may decide to change the header/footer later or even use different styles on different pages, so I am looking for a solution that does not require to hardcode the height of the header and footer. I would like that no matter the height of the header and footer, the top and bottom margins (say 1in) and the separations with the body (say 0.1in) are respected.
I have tried using the fancyhdr package for this effect in combination of the geometry package but I cannot seem to find a neat solution. My idea was to first load \usepackage[margin=1in, include head, includefoot]{geometry} to have 1in everywhere and hope that fancyhdr could adapt the body size to what remains available once the header and footer are placed. However, without further specification, the header spills over the text, or rather, the text starts too high. I have tried using the argument headheight=100pt which works if I know the exact height of my header (if I overshoot, it adds an undesired buffer), but I would have to hardcode the height of my header. One last problem, the bottom margin is not respected when the footer has multiple lines. In fact, it disappears out of the page if it is too long.
My MWE is the following:
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=100pt, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{A multiline footer\\Quite tall\\Whose height I do not want have to mention explicitly\\One more line\\And another one}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{My custom footer\\When it is longer\\It leaves the page\\And that's not what I want\\Definitely\\One more line\\And another one\\And an invisible one}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}


One possiblity is to use \smash or \raisebox and simply overlap the space above the header.  Don't bother fanychdr with details.

The problem is, at the time when the header and the footer are constructed, the body has already been made, and it can not be changed anymore. So you must set the geometry before the page construction is started.
If the height of your headers does not depend on the contents of the page, you can measure the height and then issue a \newgeometry command with the measured height. You will have to repeat this each time the header is changed (or at least when its height could change). Same for the footer.
Here is an idea:
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[showframe, margin=1in, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newlength{\HH}
\newlength{\FH}
\newcommand{\myhead}[2][]{\settoheight{\HH}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{#2}}\fancyhead[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\myfoot}[2][]{\settoheight{\FH}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{#2}}\fancyfoot[#1]{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{#2}}}
\fancyhead{}
\myhead[L]{A multiline footer\\Quite tall\\Whose height I do not want have to mention explicitly\\One more line\\And another one}
\fancyfoot{}
\myfoot[L]{My custom footer\\When it is longer\\It leaves the page\\And that's not what I want\\Definitely\\One more line\\And another one\\And an invisible one}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{headheight=\dimexpr\HH+0.3\baselineskip, footskip=\dimexpr\FH+\baselineskip, includehead, includefoot}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}

N.B. Fancyhdr version 5 will have a command to make this easier.


Thank you, it is clearer now, the geometry must be defined before the body is printed. I can manually insert the \newgeometry command where needed, but it is still unclear how I would automate this so that the header on the first page is different than that on the other pages. I will probably stick with the clumsy manual insertion for the moment and make another post later to ask this different question with an appropriate MWE.

Actually, I have tried manually inserting the \newgeometry command but it does not quite work as intended. The paragraph of lorem ipsum ends on page 3, and if I change the fancyhdr style and the geometry at this point, only the header and footer get changed, but the geometry change will only register on subsequent pages. So far I can only make this solution work if I insert a \clearpage when I believe the text should be cut, which is quite awkward.

Also \myhead is having trouble measuring the height of the object I am using in the header for some reason.
